# Is it possible to set column to null after exire date has been reached?

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to do is a subscription system basically and I want it so when users subscription has ended (went over the expiry date) I want it to set the users group back to registered and also update a column to NULL.... how would I go about this? I'm assuming with cron

But what would I put in the cron.php? For it to check if its expired in the users table?

I have tried:

```
$sql22 = "SELECT `csgo`,`id`,`group_id`,`discord`,`username` FROM `users`";
$result2 = $db->query($sql22);

$datenow = date_create('now');

        foreach($result2 as $item) {
    $omyj = $item['username'];
        $sql229 = "SELECT `expire`,`username` FROM `bans` WHERE `username` = '$omyj'";
$result29 = $db->query($sql229);
         $row_cnt = $result29->num_rows;
        $dateend = date_create($item['csgo']);
            $diff = date_diff($datenow, $dateend);
            //$out = $diff->format("Minutes:%i");
            //print_r($datenow);
            $hisuid = $item['id'];
            
    if($diff->invert) {
        if($diff->days >= 3) {
        
            if($item['csgo'] != null && $row_cnt==0){
            if($item['group_id'] == 5 || $item['group_id'] == 6){
                
            $sql31 = "UPDATE `users` SET `csgo` = NULL WHERE `id` = '$hisuid'";
             $result3 = $db->query($sql31);
             $sql314 = "UPDATE `users` SET `group_id` = '4' WHERE `id` = '$hisuid'";
             $result34 = $db->query($sql314);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could try with an `Event` in the db - set it to run every X minutes and automatically update whichever tables / records are required when the criteria is satisfied?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Behold: The [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html).

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius How would i go a bout this? Can you perhaps show me

Comment: Tip: Don't declare your SQL as a string and then execute it. Just supply the query *directly* to the function. You've got all these utterly junk variables like `$sql31` which serve no useful purpose and significantly clutter your code. Likewise, recycle your result variables, don't bother keeping them all around. This can use up a ton of memory since they cannot be freed until they are no longer referenced.

Comment: Do you not see? Sql31 sets the the CSGO column to NULL, also this code doesnt work for some reason? I run the php file in chrome but all the users who have expired sub still has the usergroup and not NULL in csgo table... any idea why?

Comment: "Doesn't work for some reason" isn't a technical diagnostic we can help with. Have you checked your server logs? Have you tried running those queries manually to see if they have the impact you think they do?

Comment: Well its not outputting to error_log, so that's working atleast

Comment: And also tadman in that link you sent to the event scheduler, there's legit no docs on it? I have no idea on how to use it! @tadman

Comment: How can you say there's "legit no docs" when that is literally the documentation and is full of links and examples?

Comment: My mistake, but there isn't any examples that fit my scenario, (e.g I need to update 2 columns like "csgo" set to null and group_id to 4" How can i do this with the event scheduler? can you atleast show a example of using it and how to do it with that? Post an answer please